# How to get the distinct keys from a JSON column in Oracle?

Tags: sql, json, oracle

For example imagine the table (`my_table`) with close to a million rows with various json data with unknown json key names:

```
| JSON_COLUMN                       | DATE       |
| --------------------------------- | ---------- |
| {"a":1, "b":2, "c",3}             | 2021-01-01 |
| {"a":111}                         | 2021-01-01 |
| {"a":11, "b":222, "c",333, "d",4} | 2021-01-02 |
| ...                               | ...        |
| ...                               | ...        |
| ...                               | ...        |
| ...                               | ...        |
```

The output must be something like:

```
a
b
c
d
...
...
```

I am able to get the distinct JSON values for a know key by doing:

```sql
select distinct json_value(JSON_COLUMN, '$.a') from my_table;
```

but not sure how to do the same for the unknown JSON keys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use [`json_dataguide`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/JSON_DATAGUIDE.html) aggregate function to access the structure of JSON documents.

Then by filtering only object steps you'll get all the keys:

```
with a(json_column, dt) as (
  select '{"a":1, "b":2, "c":3}', date '2021-01-01' from dual union all
  select '{"a":1}', date '2021-01-01' from dual union all
  select '{"a":1, "b":2, "c":3, "d":4}', date '2021-01-02' from dual
)
select distinct
  substr(elems, 3) as key_name
from json_table(
  /*Aggregate the overall structure of all JSON values*/
  (select json_dataguide(json_column) from a),
  '$[*]'
  columns (
    elems varchar(10) path '$."o:path"'
  )
)
/*Only object steps*/
where elems like '$.%'
```

| KEY_NAME |
| --- |
| a |
| b |
| c |
| d |

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/z7PoNXnP)

**UPD:**
Please note, that there are typos in the original data: commas instead of colons in the first and the third rows, which make them invalid JSON documents. Oracle silently ignores invalid JSON documents and returns `a` and `b` as the result for the original data. I've fixed those typos in the query above.